# Problems running Ubuntu 14.04 inside of a virtual machine within Virtual Box

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, virtualization

I downloaded a disk image of Ubuntu 14.04 and when tried to run it inside of a virtual machine within Virtual Box it only pops up with a blank screen, and nothing else. Could installing install guest additions fix this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: When you say you downloaded a "disk image" do you mean an ISO file or a VirtualBox image (VDI)?

Answer (score 1):

How much memory have you given to use for the Ubuntu VM?

You need at least 4GB for Unity and around 2GB for Lubuntu.

I think you didn't give enough memory to install it, and that is why it is getting stuck there.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.  You can try my solution : after increasing both the guest and video memory, my VM booted to the desktop.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Ask Ubuntu way of saying thank you.

Comment: @WarrenHill This isn't a 'thanks' answer -- the second sentence is giving a solution (may be not detailed enough to be very helpful, but still not 'thanks'.)

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to enable hardware virtualization (bios setting) first to increase the vm memory. 
[Instructions](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-Y-and-U-series-Laptops/How-to-Enable-Hardware-virtualization-on-IdeaPad-Y510p/ta-p/1394215) for lenovo ideapad (intel processor running windows)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I'd rather add the link in the comments to a good answer, but I have insufficient reputation :)